# Converting json value from integer to string format: Python

Tags: python, json, string, integer

I have a JSON file That provides the values as integers, so I need to change them to strings to continue with my project.

Here's the JSON (there's more pairs but this is for examples sake):

```
{
  "cotdata": [
    {
      "AUDLONGDEALERINTERMEDIARY": 22990,
      "GBPLONGASSETMANAGERS": 39765
    }
  ]
}
```

My code attempts to convert the values from integers to strings:

```
import json

with open("myjson.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = data['cotdata']

for key in df:
    for value in key:
        key[value] = str(key[value])
```

Although the error I get is: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Is there a way for me to correct this code? Or should I try a different logic

Comment: Got no error on pandas 1.3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're intending to do:

```py
for key in df.keys():
    df[key] = str(df[key])
```

Keep in mind this is assigning to `df` and not `data`.

I think casting the int to a string wherever it is being used would be much more efficient than this, but it's hard to say since I don't know your use-case

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the keys of each dict in the list separately.

```py
df = data['cotdata']

for o in df:
    for k, v in o.items():
        o[k] = str(v)
```